# Doubling subscriber

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I have problem with displaying subscribers. I Try to describe: I have 2 DIV containers one of them for publisher and another for subscribers. When I connect to session everything goes perfect until I disconnect from session and reconnect again. After that I begin to see 2 same subscribers, they just double. If for example I disconnect again and reconnect I will see 3 subscribers and so on. I can't understand the reason of it. Below I placed my code related to creating publisher and subscriber. Is anybody faced with the same problem? Thank you.

```
        let session;
        let st = false;
     
        /////////Initialize session
        function initializeSession(apiKey, sessionId, token) {
            if (st) {
                $.messager.alert("Attention", "You've already connected to session!", "info");
                return;
            }

            session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

            var layoutContainer = document.getElementById("subscriber");
            var layout = initLayoutContainer(layoutContainer).layout;

            session.on('streamCreated', function (event) {

                if (event.stream.videoType === 'screen') {
                    session.subscribe(event.stream, 'share_sub', {
                        insertMode: 'append',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%'
                    }, handleError);
                    makeCloseWestPanel();
                } else {
                   session.subscribe(event.stream, 'subscriber', {
                        insertMode: 'append',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: '100%'
                   }, handleError);                   
                    layout();
                }
            });

           
            // Create a publisher
            var publisher = OT.initPublisher('publisher', {
                insertMode: 'append',
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%'
            }, handleError);


            // Connect to the session
            session.connect(token, function (error) {
                // If the connection is successful, initialize a publisher and publish to the session
                if (error) {
                    handleError(error);
                } else {
                    //console.log(session.connection);
                    session.publish(publisher, handleError);
                    layout();
                    st = true;
                }
            });

        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////////

        
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        function conncect2Session() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Home/Connect2Session/',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                traditional: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (res) {
                    initializeSession(res.apiKey, res.sessionId, res.token);
                }, error: function () { alert("Did not work"); }
            });

        }
        /////////////////////////////////////////////


        /////////////////////////////////////////////
        function disconnectFromSession() {
          $.messager.confirm('Attention!', 'Are you sure you want to disconnect?', function (r) {
                        if (r) {
                            session.disconnect();
                            st = false;                           
                        }
                    });                
        }
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: How do you handle disconnects and reconnects?

Comment: @MichaelJolley I've edited my question and added functions for connecting to session and disconnecting from it. Thank you.

Comment: I've not experienced this and I use OpenTok daily. Could you provide more code or a CodePen where we can test it?

Comment: @MichaelJolley I've solved my problem already. I added    $("#subscriber").empty();    before session.subscribe(........) and after reconnecting DIV doesn't double content. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy `publisher`.
Not sure which SDK you are using, but basic methods should be the same.
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/reference/Publisher.html#destroy